# How to convert price according to currency in sequelize?

Tags: node.js, sequelize.js

```
Product :-
var Products = sequelize.define("Products", {
    name: {
      type: DataTypes.TEXT
    },
    description: {
      type: DataTypes.TEXT
    },
    sell_price: {
      type: DataTypes.DECIMAL(20, 2)
    },
    currency: {
      type: DataTypes.STRING
    }
  }, {
    underscored: true,
    paranoid: true,
    classMethods: {
      associate: function (models) {
        // associations can be defined here
      },
    },
    hooks: {
      beforeCreate: (instance) => {
      }
    }
  });
```

User :-

```
var SpreeUsers = sequelize.define("SpreeUsers", {
    full_name: {
      type: DataTypes.STRING
    },
    user_name: {
      type: DataTypes.STRING
    },
    mobile_phone_number: {
      type: DataTypes.STRING(45)
    },
    phone_number: {
      type: DataTypes.STRING(45)
    },
    email: {
      type: DataTypes.STRING
    },
    encrypted_password: {
      type: DataTypes.STRING(128)
    },
    default_currency: {
        type: DataTypes.STRING
    }
  }, {
    underscored: true,
    paranoid: true,
    hooks: {
      beforeCreate: (instance) => {
      }
    }
  });
```

Exchange-rate :-
  // This exchange rate is against USD

```
var Rate = sequelize.define("Rate", {
  currency: {
    type: DataTypes.STRING
  },
  rate: {
    type: DataTypes.DECIMAL
  }
}, {
  underscored: true,
  paranoid: true,
  hooks: {
    beforeCreate: (instance) => {
    }
  }
});
```

- We are using SEQUELIZE as ORM with node.js
- This are our "sequelize" model that we are using.
- Now We want, when user get product list price should be display according "default_currency".
- Is there any way by using it we can achieve it without manual loop ?
- Is it possible using SEQUELIZE getter and setter ?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can use the findAll method if you are using a database. For example:
db.product_list.findALL({where: price: req.params.prices}) then sort it according to that order.